# LINQ/EF Optimising group by query with count

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do a very simple group by with a count but running into issues as LINQ is throwing some very horrible SQL which is timing out. I'm running EF7 and ASP NET 5.

Here's my code -

```
var counts = (from log in db.LogTable
              where proj.Contains(log.projId)
              group log by log.callTypeId into grp
              select new 
              { 
                  key = (from temp in callTypes where temp.Id == grp.Key select temp), 
                  count = grp.Count() 
              });
```

callTypes is cached, LogTable contains over 1m records.

I've even tried removing the where clause, changing the key to select from the callTypes cache and just return the id, and also adding an orderby callTypeId but neither of these made any improvements.

Query being executed is as follows -

```
SELECT [log].[Id], [log].[callTypeId], [all other columns...] 
FROM [LogTable] AS [log] 
WHERE [log].[callTypeId] IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Does anyone have any idea whether there is a way I can force this to "SELECT callTypeId, count(*) FROM LogTable WHERE... GROUP BY callTypeId" to stop it from returning all the records and doing the grouping on the application side please? Or do I need to revert to Stored Procedures ??

**UPDATE -**

As explained above, replacing (from temp in callTypes where temp.Id == grp.Key select temp) with just grp.Key gives the same query so this is not the issue.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the exact type of `callTypes`?  When you say it's "cached", do you mean it's an `IQuerable`?  If it's actual in-memory data then it has no business in a EF query to the DB.  Just do a group by on `LogTable` to get the count and then do the key mapping with `callTypes` in-memory.

Comment: callTypes is in-memory, but the problem occurs even without this, i.e if I had select new { key = grp.Key, count = grp.Count() } - the query on the SQL is still the same

I can even reduce this to -

    var counts = (from log in db.LogTable
                         group log by log.callTypeId into grp
                         select new { key = grp.Key, count = grp.Count() });

Same problem occurs

Comment: key = (from temp in callTypes where temp.Id == grp.Key select temp).. Pretty sure making a new query inside a select statement like this is bad idea. Join LogTable and calltypes and then proceed?

Comment: What if you do something like `group log.Id by log.callTypeId into grp` instead?  What you group shouldn't matter since you just want the count.

Comment: Updated my question - the new query is not the issue, I've replaced this already but the same query is produced. 

@juharr - tried but no difference I'm afraid!

Comment: The issue is called "EF Core". It has been released with a lot of bugs into Sql generation (and not only) part. But it has a "feature" of running part of the queries in memory when it cannot translate some part to SQL, so this is what you got. Add the following line inside `OnConfiguring`: `optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(bulder => bulder.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));` and you'll see hat I mean. Currently there is no workaround, wait for v.1.1 or go back to EF6

Comment: @IvanStoev - Thanks for this! I can't seem to get ConfigureWarnings to work as it keeps saying does not contain a definition for this... but I've now searched around differently and can see many people with this issue which seems to be down to what you are saying. It's a shame, I've come across so many issues in EF7 and tried to work my way around things to stick it out, but I may have to give in and revert to EF6 very soon... Thanks again.